# SQL Server database restore - missing users

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, security, authentication

I have restored a database for an application that uses SQL Server logins for security. The restore is complete and functional, although there is a small issue.

The database users are present (`Server->Database->Security->Users`) but they are not present in the server logins (`Server->Security->Logins`). This is because I restored the DB on a different server than where the backup was taken.

So it seems I cannot reset their passwords anymore. AFAIK, you can only do this from `Server->Security->Logins` and not from the database security itself.

Is there anyway to quickly "synchronize" the whole thing so users show at both places ?

Thanks.

Comment: Pinal Dave has a script to help [migrate logins](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/03/01/sql-server-transfer-the-logins-and-the-passwords-between-instances-of-sql-server-2005/). Does that help you? After migrating the logins, you may need to confirm/reset db users.

Comment: That looks interesting. Thanks.

Comment: Or take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867986/linking-users-to-login-after-restoring-a-sql-server-2005-database